# Textblock as Link conditionally

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hyperlink

I have a Label with text property bound to a class:

```
 <TextBlock Visibility="Hidden" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding DisplayText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="10"></TextBlock>
```

If that `DisplayText` is a link than a hyperlink should be used. The class I am binding to also provides the `Uri` and a boolean `isLink`. I tried putting a `Hyperlink` element inside of the `Textblock` and set its `NavigateUri` to the `Uri` from the class but that did not work for me.
Does anyone have a clean solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use both controls and make their visibility change based on `isLink` property.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock>
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Uri}"
                   RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
        </Hyperlink>
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLink}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLink}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: If isLink is false there still is the blue underline of the link and also even if isLink is true both TextBlocks are displayed. The fact that they are in the Datatemplate of a Listbox should not influence it right? http://imgur.com/BpKfeIx

Comment: Actually, that's exactly the problem. The `DataContext` of each item in the `ListBox` is the respective element in the `ListBox.ItemsSource`'s list. That's why the binding is not working, it's binding to the isLink of the list's item, witch doesn't have an isLink property. I'm making myself clear?
To fix that, change the binding to something like 
`Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Path=DataContext.isLink}"`

Comment: The Listbox Datasource is bound to a ObservableCollection of a class providing "DisplayText" and "isLink" for each item.

Comment: Have you tried changing the bindings?
When you have a collection binded to an `ItemsSource` of an `ItemsControl` each interface item created through your  `DataTemplate` will have the the respective collection item automatically set as the `DataContext`.
For instance, let's say you have an `ObservableCollection<Point> Points` property in your VM class. In this situation, if you bind the `ItemsSource` property to the `Points` property, the `DataContext` of your `DataTemplate` will be a Point, not the VM class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can bind a template according to the property.

```
 <ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLink}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"  >
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock>
                                                 <Hyperlink  NavigateUri="{Binding DataContext.Url, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,      
                        AncestorType= ContentControl} }">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.DisplayText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,      
                        AncestorType=ContentControl} }"/>
                                                </Hyperlink>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLink}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.DisplayText,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,      
                        AncestorType=ContentControl} }"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
```